# Apply different functions (taken from a list), into a For loop

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica

I have a list of functions:
`DisUFuncList = Table[x^2, {n, 1, M}];`

and a list of arguments `y`. My goal is to receive the sum 
`DisUFuncList[[i]] [ y[[i]] ]`.

Here is the code:

```
    DisUFuncList = Table[x^2, {n, 1, M}];
Sum2=0;For[i = 1, i <= Length[y], i++, 
Sum2 = Sum2 + Function[x, DisUFuncList[[i]] ] [ y[[i]] ]    ];
```

This is also not working:

```
Apply[Function[DisUFuncList[[2]]], {2} ]
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: yes, at the beginning I want this list to contain M copies of `x^2` , but after that I can change it.

Answer (score 3):

For example

```
DisUFuncList[x_] := Table[x^n, {n, 2, 6}]
y = Range[2, 6];
Sum[DisUFuncList[y[[i]]][[i]], {i, Length[y]}] == Sum[i^i, {i, 2, 6}]
(*
-> True
*)
```

Please remember: `Looping in Mathematica is generally considered a bad practice.`

**Edit**

Regarding your comment, there are many ways to do that.
Here is one:

```
M = 5;
DisUFuncList = Table[x^n, {n, 1, M}]
y = Range[M]
Sum[DisUFuncList[[i]] /. x -> y[[i]], {i, Length@y}]
(*
 -> 3413  (==Sum[i^i, {i, 5}])
*)
```

Comment: ok, thanks.
However, with this approach we calculate many redundant values.
Do you know some way to interpret expression as a function directly, not to generate a new list every time?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of issues here, some of which get in the way of understanding (mine, anyway) exactly what you're after.

First, x^2 isn't a function in Mathematica. Functions ought to look like #^2& or however you've defined them. In a discussion that can get mired in arcane and stunt-like Mathematica forms, I'll try to keep some transparency by defining my function list as:

```
    funcList = {Sin, Cos,Tan}
```

Second, it appears you want to thread that list of functions over a list of arguments,

```
    argList = {a1, a2, a3} say
```

part by part, and, ultimately, if I understand the question correctly, you want an expression that'll generate the result

```
    Sin[a1] + Cos[a2] + Tan[a3]
```

You can get MapThread to make the first step using the form

```
    MapThread[#1@#2&, {funcList, argList}]
```

Then the sum is

```
    Plus@@%
```

Niftier, but maybe more opaque would be:

```
    Inner[#1@#2&,funcList,argList]
```

QED for my interpretation of the question.

I hope this helped answer the question you were actually asking.

Fred Klingener

Comment: **QED** are the Latin initials for "quod erat demonstrandum", which (if both my Latin and English don't fail me) means something like "which was the thing to be demonstrated". So perhaps is not used properly in your answer.